# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float (Python2)

Tags: python

```
import math

a=[100,4,5,10,3,1]

def swap(a,b):

        temp=a

        a=b

        b=temp
for i in range(len(a),int(len(a)/2),-1):

        l=i

        print l

        print int(math.ceil(int((l)/2.0)))

        print a[int(math.ceil(int((l)/2.0)))]

        print math.ceil(a[int((l)/2.0)])

        print a[l-1]

        while(l>1 and a[l-1] < a[int(math.ceil(int((l)/2.0)))]):

                swap(a[l-1],a[int(math.ceil(int((l)/2.0)))])

                print l

                l= math.ceil(int((l))/2.0)

print a
```

Output:

```
6

3

10

10.0

1

6

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "heap.py", line 15, in <module>
while(l>1 and a[l-1] < a[int(math.ceil(int((l)/2.0)))]):

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
```

I have checked many questions on stackoverflow with same query, I
tried using the // as well but the error is persistent. I am using the
int value as I printed and tested. Can anyone redirect me to a
question with similar issue( if this duplicate) or help me with this
error?

Comment: `l = math.ceil(int((l))/2.0)` this line makes `l` a float

Comment: Your `swap` function does nothing.

Comment: @BanishedBot I converted it to int in the while loop, I was just printing the value to check.

Comment: it's a `int` in the for loop, but a `float` in the while loop still. try printing it in the while loop

Comment: Can you point ```[int(math.ceil(int((l)/2.0)))]``` ?